# Init a new project by using Mean.Io

Tags: mean.io

I have created a new Mean project. Now I would create my own project. I have realized that I should create a new package. I have execute the command `mean package myOwnPackage` and a new package has been added to the folder `packages`. Inside that one there are other package. I don't understand how to run the project through grunt that show only my application instead of the built in packages articles

Answer (score 0):

In packages folder, delete `/packages/articles`, when `grunt`, you will see your package name in navigation bar. `system`, `access` and `users` cannot be delete, or it will cause errors.

Comment: but I would like to develop and deploy a black web site without using that page. Let suppose I would like to have a black web page where I start to place my elements. I should modify system folder files right?

Comment: @Mazzy Yes, in that scenario, you have to modify `/system`

Answer (score 0):

1. mean init - looks like you did that.
2. delete the 'articles' package, it's an example
3. customize your app:

These templates load your Angular app into the browser.

```
- packages/system/server/views/index.html - this extends default.html.
- packages/system/server/views/layouts/default.html - this is the bottom-most template in your app.
- packages/system/server/views/includes/foot.html,head.html - these are used by default.html to build a homepage.  Note that head.html is head tag not menu.
```

Now Browser has loaded your app.  It's an angular app, so angular starts to change the DOM of the loaded page.

```
- packages/system/public/views/index.html - This is what angular puts on the \ route
- packages/system/public/views/header.html - This is what angular puts in the menu
```

Does that answer your question?

If you want to make a black website, figure out where you want the black to be.